# How to Select from two tables in 1 query in Salesforce SOQL iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce, soql

How can i combine this two request in salesforce SOQL query into 1 single request in iOS:

```
NSString *theRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID = '%@'", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]];
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

and

```
NSString *theRequest2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT CompetitorName FROM OpportunityCompetitor where OpportunityID = '%@'", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]];
SFRestRequest *request2 = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest2];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request2 delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this subquery:

`SELECT Name, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID IN (SELECT OpportunityID FROM OpportunityCompetitor where OpportunityID = '%@')`

Comment: ERROR|SFNetworkOperation|callDelegateDidFailWithError The left operand field in the where expression for outer query should be an id field which matches the select, cannot use: 'OpportunityID'

Comment: @AldrinEquila: I have cross checked with my database, It should be work perfectly.

Comment: Can you please show me how you use that subquery with code?

Comment: NSString *theRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID IN (SELECT CompetitorName FROM OpportunityCompetitor where OpportunityID = '%@')", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]];
    SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:theRequest];
    [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];

Comment: @AldrinEquila - Check that `IN (SELECT <field-name>`. It should be `OpportunityID`. That's why its giving you an error. Here from inner query you are returning `CompetitorName` and from outer query you are comparing with `OpportunityID` is wrong. Operand from both side should be same.

Comment: The query is suppose to be like this:

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, OpportunityID FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityID IN (SELECT OpportunityID FROM OpportunityCompetitor where OpportunityID = '%@')", [companyDic objectForKey:@"Id"]]`

Comment: its working now. but it doesn't show the product name anymore. i want to display the competitorName and product name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63217/discussion-between-kampai-and-aldrin-equila).